# Searching for value in Datatable with list in column C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable (say dt) where one of the columns is map_ids which is a list of ids as follows:

| Map_ids |
| --- |
| 104400,100197 |
| 100142,272189 |
| 101216,272145,272146 |
| 29,272188 |
| 110016,100206 |
| 100117,272019,110355 |
| 3,109997 |
| 23,110438 |

I want to search in the datatable if an id exists in the map_ids column and return the row.

For example I want to get the row with id '3' in it for which I tried using the code:

```
dt.Select("map_ids like '%3%'")[0]["map_ids"].ToString();
```

But what happens in this case is that it returns the following row: `100117,272019,110355`

Expected Row: `3,109997`

Best way would be to split this string and check if the array contains the id but not sure how to achieve that. Any suggestions welcome and wouldn't mind using Linq as well.

Comment: List<DataRow> results = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Map_id").Contains("3")).ToList();  You can add Regex to do the contains.

Answer (score 0):

This following query is unexpected due to begin with % will filter something like 'xxxxx3xxx'.

```
dt.Select("map_ids like '%3%'")[0]["map_ids"].ToString();
```

Try to use

```
dt.Select("('H,'+ map_ids + ',T') LIKE '%,3,%'")[0]["map_ids"].ToString();
```

Moreover, maybe you could add some logic to check the data exists or not. It has probability of throwing exceptions.